# Stream response in spring boot using spring mvc rest

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am trying to send OutStream in ResponseEntity but it gives me an error "Could not find acceptable representation"

OutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

```
        if (result.get(Orchestrator.SUCCESS_RESPONSE) != null) {
            logger.info("Received successful response [{}]", result.get(Orchestrator.SUCCESS_RESPONSE));
            try {
                GraphSONWriter.outputGraph((Graph) result.get(Orchestrator.SUCCESS_RESPONSE), stream);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            /*stream = outputStream -> {
                GraphSONWriter.outputGraph((Graph) result.get(Orchestrator.SUCCESS_RESPONSE), outputStream);
            };*/
            //return ResponseEntity.ok().header("Accept", "application/json").body(stream);
            httpHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
            return new ResponseEntity<OutputStream>(stream, httpHeaders, HttpStatus.OK);
```

I would really appreciate some help, thank you.

Comment: Have you tried the obvious thing: transform the ByteArrayOutputSTream to a byte array, and return a ResponseEntity<byte[]>?

Comment: Yes I tried and it just give me weird mix of characters. I want to stream json response.

Comment: Can you show what the content of `stream` is in your example, and what would you like it to look like?